Opening secure client website in webview throwing security Validation exception
There is client certificate requires to access client secure website,So, if I access this secure website by uploading certificate in system browser. I can able to access the secure website.
But accessing same website in webview of JavaFX application, by passing client certificate programmatically, is throwing, below error:
    javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|A1|JavaFX Application Thread|2024-05-31 17:09:41.320 IST|SSLCipher.java:466|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|A1|JavaFX Application Thread|2024-05-31 17:09:41.321 IST|SSLCipher.java:466|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry =  ChaCha20-Poly1305 KeyUpdate 2^37. CHACHA20-POLY1305:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|30|Finalizer|2024-05-31 17:09:41.406 IST|SSLSocketImpl.java:577|duplex close of SSLSocket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|30|Finalizer|2024-05-31 17:09:41.406 IST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1781|close the SSL connection (passive)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|62|HttpClient-1-Worker-0|2024-05-31 17:09:41.501 IST|TransportContext.java:370|Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (
"throwable" : {
  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:285)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:632)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473)t

Even I tried adding certificate in system keystore also.
Need help in resolving this issue
I am using Java-17 and JavaFx-17

Probable duplicate: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

@jewelsea, I am using java-17 and JavaFx-17, same has been updated. I am checking the solution link you shared.

Debugging SSL can be notoriously difficult.  Steps if you need to suffer are at Debugging SSL/TLS Connections.  Hopefully, the info in the potential duplicate will allow you to get to a solution without extensive debugging.

Internally, the WebView implementation in JavaFX 17 when running on Java 17 will, by default, use the Java 17 HttpClient for connections, so there isn't anything JavaFX or WebView specific about your issue. Any test client you write that uses a standard HttpClient would experience the same issue when accessing the same URL.
